# imshow shows small white blocks in the corners of the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a heat map for a set of data i have.

```
file1 = open('file1').readlines()[:]
x1=[]
y1=[]
z1=[]
for i in range(len(file1)):  
    line = file1[i].split()[:]    
    x1.append(float(line[0]))
    y1.append(float(line[1]))
    z1.append(float(line[2]))

xi = np.linspace(min(x1), max(x1))
yi = np.linspace(min(y1), max(y1))
[xx,yy] = np.meshgrid(x1,y1,sparse=True)
zz = griddata(x1,y1,z1,xi,yi)

fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(zz,extent=(min(x1),max(x1),min(y1),max(y1)),origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlim([min(x1),max(x1)])
plt.ylim([min(y1),max(y1)])
plt.show()
```

this produces

[image]

(I have ommited the part of the code that scatters the filled circles...)

Notice the weird white blocks in the top left and bottom right corners. Can anyone guess (or know) what might be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you have not-`NaN` data in this region?

Comment: Also your readingis strangely manual. Cosider using `x1, y1, z1 = np.genfromtxt('file1', unpack=True)`